# ajaxcontroltoolkit tabcontainer style themes css

Tags: themes, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

This link: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/ajaxcontroltoolkit_tabcontaine.html
has a great collection of themes for asp.net tabcontrol. Can someone help me find out where i can download css for all the themes shown in that page?
I tried all the links in the page but none of that seem to have the downloadable css info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link is no longer valid in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I can help you access some of his stylesheets. Go to this blog entry of his: [(blog entry)](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/09/more_sample_ajaxcontroltoolkit.html) . Now, use the Way Back Machine @ archive.org and paste the CSS link into the way back machine text box. Select the date that was recorded by the WBM and you will be able to access it.

[Example](http://web.archive.org/web/20110511192617/http://mattberseth2.com/tab_theme_II/StyleSheet.css)

You can now get an idea of what he is doing with his themes. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found something not better than yours.

[Check it out](http://digdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/03/aspnet-ajax-tab-control-colorful-themes.html)

I hope you to help.

Comment: hey thank you kst! but i was looking to use one of the themes that Matt has in his site .. still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_header
        {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue" , Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight:bold;
            display: block;

        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_outer
        {
            border-color: #222;
            color: #222;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 3px;
            border:solid 1px #d7d7d7;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_inner
        {
            border-color: #666;
            color: #666;
            padding: 3px 10px 2px 0px;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_outer
        {
            background-color:#9c3;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_inner
        {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_outer
        {
            border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #d7d7d7;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner
        {
            color: #000;
            border-color: #333;
        }
        .MyTabStyle .ajax__tab_body
        {
            font-family: verdana,tahoma,helvetica;
            font-size: 10pt;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-top-width: 0;
            border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;
            border-top-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
```